# An operation error occured enumerating DirectoryEntry group

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I've been going through previous post trying to resolve this issue all morning, but none of them seem to work.

I have been righting a user management interface for AD for our course admins, the idea being to only display exactly what they need, while the solution works fine on the dev servers, i get the above error on prod.

I have tried every thing i can find, like HostingEnvironment.Impersonate, promoting the service account to a domain admin, but noting works.

```
public static List<GroupPrincipal> GetGroups(string client)
{
        List<GroupPrincipal> List = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

        DirectoryEntry ou = null;
        GroupPrincipal group = null;
        PrincipalContext context = null;

        if (domain.Path.ToLower().Contains(DevDN.ToLower()))
        {
            context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                DevDom,
                DevDN,
                DevService,
                DevServicePass);
        }
        else
        {
            context = new PrincipalContext(
                ContextType.Domain,
                LiveDom,
                LiveDN,
                LiveService,
                LiveServicePass);
        }

        DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(domain, "(&(ou=" + client + ")(objectClass=organizationalUnit))");
        try
        {
            ou = new DirectoryEntry(searcher.FindOne().Path);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteError("SUGM.ADLink.GetGroups", "Unable to locate client: " + ex.Message);
            List = null;
            return List;
        }
        try
        {
            foreach (DirectoryEntry groups in ou.Children)
            {
                if (groups.SchemaClassName == "group")
                {
                    string name = groups.Name.Replace("CN=", "");
                    group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, name);
                    List.Add(group);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Log.WriteError("SUGM.ADLink.GetGroups", "Unable to add groups to list: " + ex.Message);
            List = null;
            return List;
        }

        return List;
    }
```

While debugging I have check and all the correct values are being passed, but it alway fails on the foreach block.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong.

Cheers

Comment: Why are you mixing `PrincipalContext` and `GroupPrincipal` from the   `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (.NET 3.5) namespace with `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` (.NET 2.0) from the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace?? Doesn't really make sense, and won't work very well... please explain what you're trying to do in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid mixing the `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespaces - that's not a very good strategy!

You can do all you want in S.DS.AM (.NET 3.5), too! And much easier, too.

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context and specify the initial container to work from
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN", "OU=YourStartingPoint,DC=YourCompany,DC=com");

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Woops hadnt even noticed that, how naughty of me. Your solution works thanks alot